# I can't link my CSS file to my HTML file. But it is working fine with Live Server. What's wrong?

Tags: html, css

I had a CSS and a HTML file in the same folder on the desktop. Earlier  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />` was working fine. Now I've made two folders HTML and CSS to separate the files. So, now I use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/style.css" />`. It works perfectly fine on Live Server in VS Code but when I open index.html normally in a browser, the CSS file does not link, neither do the images which are in the img folder now. I've tried `href = "./CSS/style.css"`, `href="/style.css"`. It works ONLY IN LIVE SERVER!!! HELP!

Comment: remove the slash before CSS `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css" />`

Comment: or if the index file is in the HTML folder then do it like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/style.css" />`

Comment: check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) to learn about paths an how to use them to navigate through directories, it may be a bit tricky at te beginning but the more you practice it the easier it becomes

Comment: I have tried href="CSS/style.css" too. Doesn't work.

Comment: You have to understand the logic behind it before continuing because you will need it again in the future, see if the answer I posted helps you understand and try the hyperlink practice for easier learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have one main directory that has three sub-directories

```
-MainDirectory
    -HTML
    -CSS
    -Images
```

Now each file lives inside it's directory...

```
-MainDirectory
    -HTML
        -index.html
    -CSS
        -style.css
    -Images
        image1.jpg
        image2.jpg
```

The path for accessing the site is MainDirectory/HTML/index.html

Now, the main file (index.html) needs to use the stylesheet placed in MainDirectory/CSS and the way to achieve this is by manipulating the path to go one directory backwards and from there navigate to css so the code would look like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/style.css" />
```

What the code does now is that it navigates from HTML to MainDirectory and from there it goes to CSS where it reads the data written in style.css.

The same happens with the images, if you want to access an image you will have to pull the data from `../Images/image1.jpg"`

Another way to navigate through the directories is to use a slash `/` as a starting point so for an example if you are using MainDirectory as your starting point, you can also access the stylesheet like this `/CSS/style.css`... This tells the code to start from the very first folder that exists in this path (in our case it is MainDirectory) and from there navigate to where you need to go...

Understand this by creating hyperlinks...

```
<a href="/style.css">Hover Me!</a>
```

Place this code in your `index.html`, then open `index.html` in your browser and hover over the link.

The path to where this clickable item goes will show in the bottom-left corner of the browser and by being able to see the path you can easily manipulate it... You can see it's starting point and see if you need to go a directory up or not, you can see where you are and where you need to go, play with it, change it until you understand the logic behind it